# Event to detect iPhone Synchronization

Tags: objective-c, ios4, event-handling

I am creating an application to edit images present in the iPhone Camera Roll and Photo Library. Due to the way my application is designed, I am unable to enable auto-sync.

**My question is that, is there a delegate/event handler that fires when the iTunes synchronization starts and ends?** I intend to freeze my application when the sync starts and refresh my application when the sync ends.

I am using iPhone 4.0 running iOS 5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware no notifications of the device sync operation are posted, however you can listen to notifications posted by `ALAssetsLibrary` which you may be able to use to get what you want.

Relevant docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3